# How to disable ErrorPageFilter in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-boot

I'm creating a [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) service that should be running on Tomcat.
I'm using Spring Boot for my application, similar to:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class)
public class AppConfig {
}
```

My webservice (example):

```
@Component
@WebService
public class MyWebservice {

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult
    public String test() {
        throw new MyException();
    }
}

@WebFault
public class MyException extends Exception {
}
```

**Problem:**
Whenever I throw an exception within the webservice class, the following message is logged on the server:

> ErrorPageFilter: Cannot forward to error page for request
>   [/services/MyWebservice] as the response has already been committed.
>   As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your
>   application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able
>   to resolve this problem by setting
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false

**Question:**
How can I prevent this?

Comment: Can you share some code that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To disable the `ErrorPageFilter` in Spring Boot (tested with 1.3.0.RELEASE), add the following beans to your Spring configuration:

```
@Bean
public ErrorPageFilter errorPageFilter() {
    return new ErrorPageFilter();
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean disableSpringBootErrorFilter(ErrorPageFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(filter);
    filterRegistrationBean.setEnabled(false);
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

Comment: Were you using an embedded container for this? Or a war deployment?

Comment: Embedded tomcat has ErrorPageFilter stripped out from my understanding...

Answer (score 20):

The simpliest way to disable ErrorPageFilter is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public App() {
    super();
    setRegisterErrorPageFilter(false); // <- this one
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(App.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the official way to do it, according to the bug report in GitHub. This is the fix they added: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/11d59df3fd71a656a7869ace4303a8d72e6f777c

Comment: This solution does not work since Spring Boot 1.5.0.

Comment: @Sõber it's possibly a bug, as you can see nothing has changed here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blame/11d59df3fd71a656a7869ace4303a8d72e6f777c/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/web/SpringBootServletInitializer.java

Answer (score 11):

```
    @SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        //set register error pagefilter false
        setRegisterErrorPageFilter(false);

        builder.sources(MyApplication.class);
        return builder;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to tell the WebSphere container to stop ErrorPageFiltering. To achieve this we have to define a property in the server.xml file.

`<webContainer throwExceptionWhenUnableToCompleteOrDispatch="false" invokeFlushAfterService="false"></webContainer>`

Alternatively, you also can disable it in the spring application.properties file

```
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter=off
```

I prefer the first way.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I found in the sources that the `ErrorPageFilter.java` has the following code:

```
private void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    ErrorWrapperResponse wrapped = new ErrorWrapperResponse(response);
    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, wrapped);
        int status = wrapped.getStatus();
        if (status >= 400) {
            handleErrorStatus(request, response, status, wrapped.getMessage());
            response.flushBuffer();
        }
        else if (!request.isAsyncStarted() && !response.isCommitted()) {
            response.flushBuffer();
        }
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        handleException(request, response, wrapped, ex);
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
}
```

As you can see when you throw an exception and return a response code >= 400  it will do some code. there should be some additional check if the response was already committed or not.

The way to remove the ErrorPageFilter is like this

```
protected WebApplicationContext run(SpringApplication application) {
    application.getSources().remove(ErrorPageFilter.class);
    return super.run(application);
}
```

Chris

Answer (score -3):

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer 
{
   private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Application.class);

   public Application()
   {
       super();
       setRegisterErrorPageFilter(false);
   }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give a look at: [How to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)