# @ControllerAdvice doesn't process exception

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception, spring-boot

In my Rest API created in Spring Boot I am trying to indicate that resource has not been found to throw an exception and do exception handling with `@ControllerAdvice`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public void notFound() {
        // do something...
    }

}
```

my exception class:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public final class NotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public NotFoundException() {
    }

    public NotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

and testing method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/no", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void notExists() {
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
```

but instead `HTTP 404` is throw `HTTP 500` and `GlobalControllerExceptionHandler` is not activated.

**Update 1:**

From `catalina.out`:

> 2015-09-12 22:42:59.510 ERROR 71872 --- [o-8080-exec-140]
>   o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter     : Cannot forward to error
>   page for request [/persons/no/] as the response has already been
>   committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code.
>   If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may
>   be able to resolve this problem by setting
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false

Comment: Turn on Spring's DEBUG logging and post the result of a request-response cycle.

Comment: I added Tomcat error log message.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner - no effect.

Comment: OK, removed my prior comment. I believe the `@ControllerAdvice` mechanism is working well. You're having problem with the `ErrorPageFilter`. Remove that filter and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31858680/1315357):

```
@Bean
    public ErrorPageFilter errorPageFilter() {
        return new ErrorPageFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean disableSpringBootErrorFilter(ErrorPageFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(filter);
        filterRegistrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }
```