# Spring boot unformatted BadCredentialsException

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot configured service. Normally I test it locally then deploy this as a .war to Tomcat on AWS ElasticBeansStalk.

The thing is: format of BadCredentialsException threw at AWS vary, comparing to my development environment (where I have embedded Tomcat at the service, spring boot's default), for example:

If I throw a BadCredentials exception locally I get a JSON error:

```
{
"timestamp": 1445622806489,
"status": 401,
"error": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Invalid user/password",
"path": "/user"
}
```

If if run into the same error with the deployed service, I get this unformatted mess:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.23 - Error report</title>
    <style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 401 - Invalid user/password</h1>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>
        <b>type</b> Status report
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>message</b>
        <u>Invalid user/password</u>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>description</b>
        <u>This request requires HTTP authentication.</u>
    </p>
    <hr class="line">
        <h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.23</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any configuration I could do with Spring so I could force the former format on all error messages, even when exporting to .war?

Comment: Are you accessing the endpoint in the same way (e.g. browser/curl/other)? With default settings spring-boot will try to return html error page if no "Accept: application/json" header is found in the http request. To change that behavior you can use the solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170586/how-to-disable-errorpagefilter-in-spring-boot/31858680#31858680

Comment: Yes, I'm accessing them in the same way, by Postman extension. The request has the mentioned header, also. I've tried your suggested solution with no success, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `ErrorPageFilter`, not needed at the embedded environment but used at the non-embedded one, thus, when deployed to the .war it may cause the problem depending on the configuration, as stated in [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1548) bug report at Spring Boot's github.

One solution to the problem is to verify that the default Spring Boot Security settings are enabled, removing any `@EnableWebSecurity` or adding `/error` to the excluded paths of the application.

Comment: Could you explain how to add "/error" to the excluded paths?