# ErrorPageFilter - Cannot forward to error page for request

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, tomcat8

I often saw such kind of error logs on the running server:

---

*ERROR o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter - Cannot forward to error page for request [/api/login] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false*

---

My server running & development environment:

```
Ubuntu 14.04
Tomcat 8
Sprint Framework: 4.3.1
Sprint Boot: 1.5.9
Kotlin: 1.2.21
```

According to [one question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170586/how-to-disable-errorpagefilter-in-spring-boot), the following code which I have added (transformed as Kotlin code) to try removing this error log but doesn't work.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@EnableTransactionManagement
open class MyApplication: SpringBootServletInitializer()  {

    init {
        setRegisterErrorPageFilter(false)    <<<< I added this func call to try fix
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            SpringApplication.run(MyApplication::class.java, *args)
        }
    }
}
```

Could anybody give a further hint? about how to fix the error.

Comment: is there a specific exception that comes after your ErrorPageFilter error? do you have the full stack trace?