# Spring Boot & WAS 8.5 deployment

Tags: spring-boot, websphere

I am trying to deploy Spring boot application to WAS 8.5 but facing some issues. The application is working fine in tomcat and running successfully. In Websphere 8.5 it is deploying successfully but not working.
But on hitting the soap service endpoint:

```
***`[4/9/18 14:36:40:012 EDT] 000000c4 SystemOut     O 09-04-2018 14:36:40.011 [WebContainer : 1] ERROR o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.deliverOrBuffer - Cannot forward to error page for request [/customerinfo/soap] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false.`***
```

After the server starts I see the below successful start logs of the application:

---

```
[4/9/18 14:36:07:160 EDT] 00000048 SystemOut     O 09-04-2018 14:36:07.159 [Default : 1] INFO  c.a.a.s.CustInfoServiceApplication.deliverOrBuffer - Started CustInfoServiceApplication in 32.202 seconds (JVM running for 557.392)
[4/9/18 14:36:07:282 EDT] 00000048 SystemOut     O 09-04-2018 14:36:07.282 [Default : 1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.deliverOrBuffer - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
[4/9/18 14:36:07:353 EDT] 00000048 SystemOut     O 09-04-2018 14:36:07.352 [Default : 1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.deliverOrBuffer - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 69 ms
[4/9/18 14:36:07:443 EDT] 00000048 SystemOut     O 09-04-2018 14:36:07.443 [Default : 1] WARN  c.i.w.r.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.logToJSR47Logger - WSVR0221I: Application started: cust-info-ear
```

---

Anyone faced any similar issue or can guide would be helpful.

**EDIT 1:** - the difference I found is that on Tomcat it is hitting the MessageDispatcherServlet class and on WAS 8.5 it is hitting the DispatcherServlet class.

Comment: `If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false.` Did you try this?

Comment: Yeah I tried it, its not giving the logger but instead coming "This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback." on SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue and got that resolved. You can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57970873/7594119)